# Code on getting every even letter as capital in a word

Tags: python

Can someone explain the code please?

```
def my_func(st):   
  operations = (str.lower, str.upper)    
  return ''.join(operations[i%2](x) for i, x in enumerate(st))
```

I am getting the desired output.
but I am unaware of the 3rd line in the code

Comment: What part(s) do you not understand? Do you know `enumerate()`? Do you know `%`? Do you know `str.join()`? Tuple element access, string element access? For loops? List comprehensions & generator expressions?

Comment: There are multiple things on line 3, ask about **one specific** thing that you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the tricky part is `operations[i%2](x)`.

This is a trick/hack to select between two functions, but it's really not readable/explicit and shouldn't be used in real life.

`i%2` returns `1` if `i` is odd and `0` if `i` is even. Thus for each letter in `st` that is enumerated as `x`/`i` for the value/position (with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)). You code selects between `str.lower` and `str.upper` by indexing the tuple `operations` with `0`/`1` depending on the value of `i`.

Then it joins all letters in a single string (with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)).

A better approach could be to use a ternary:

```
def my_func(st):
    return ''.join(x.upper() if i%2 else x.lower()
                   for i, x in enumerate(st))
```

Or [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), which is a bit similar to the original logic but more explicit IMO:

```
from itertools import cycle

def my_func(st):
    c = cycle((str.lower, str.upper))
    return ''.join(next(c)(x) for x in st)
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate  is used to iterate over the characters of the input string  along with their indices and returns pairs of (index, character). Then, alternately applies str. lower and str. upper to each character based on its index (operations[i%2] means for each index that is even ), and then joins the results into a single string